# Laravel-VueJS App - How to prevent Axios post from reloading the page (using no form)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, debugging, axios, refresh

I'm not even using a form only two radio input and a method to update data, but this causes an unwanted and very annoying page refresh. All the other topics about this I found on Stackoverflow and the web, involves a form or the live reload feature of Vue/React and I'm using none of these.

This is really annoying as I can't seem to find the issue, using breakpoints, I only notice that the page reload happens right after Axios is done with the post request.

Here my html:

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label class="control-label mr-3" for="status"><strong>{{ __('Region Mode') }}</strong> </label>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label mr-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="default_region_mode" v-model="region_mode"
                        @click.prevent="updateRegionMode('single_region')" :checked="region_mode ==='single_region'"
                        class="form-check-input" value="single_region" />{{ __('Single Region') }}<i class="input-frame"></i>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-2">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" name="default_region_mode" v-model="region_mode"
                        @click.prevent="updateRegionMode('multiple_region')" :checked="region_mode ==='multiple_region'"
                        class="form-check-input" value="multiple_region" />{{ __('Multiple Region') }}<i class="input-frame"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my vue JS method:

```
updateRegionMode(value) {

            if (this.region_mode === value)
                return;

            this.is_updating = true;

            axios.post('settings/update/region-mode', {
                    value,
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.is_updating = false;
                    let res = response.data;
                    console.log(res);
                    if (res.code === 200) {
                        this.region_mode = value;
                        window.notify('success', 'Success', res.message, true);
                    } else {
                        window.notify('error', 'Oops !!', res.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch(({
                    response: error
                }) => {
                    this.is_updating = false;
                    console.log(error);
                    window.errorNotify(error, "Oops !!");
                });

        }
```

Comment: - is it same case on axios success & failure?
- If you preserve log on chrome dev tool are you seeing `console.log(res)` / `console.log(error)` ?
- If you comment out axios call completely does it stops page refresh?
- If yes to above point, if you comment out all in succcess and failure does it stops page refresh?
- Are you able to provide working example / fiddle or something?

Comment: @PerdeepSingh if I comment out axios completely it, does reload, but also the radiobuttons do not toggle when i click, but the method still get called (i can see that with console log). Error case doesnt happent, but in successful `console.log(res)` appers in chrome console. i took it out from a project to make a fiddle out of it will take me quite some time to rebuild some parts, if very neccessary i'll have to do it :/